# how to play video in videoview by using rtsp link

Tags: android, android-videoview, rtsp

i am trying to play youtube videos in videoview by using rtsp url but i am getting "Can't play this error" i am using this code to play video in videoview

```
String SrcPath = "rtsp://v5.cache1.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQnhycnrJQ8qmRMYESARFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYPj_hYjnq6uUTQw=/0/0/0/video.3gp";
        VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
           myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(SrcPath));
           myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
           myVideoView.requestFocus();
           myVideoView.start();
```

this is my logcat error

```
01-14 10:41:26.844: D/libEGL(2643): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
01-14 10:41:26.914: D/libEGL(2643): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
01-14 10:41:26.974: D/libEGL(2643): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
01-14 10:41:27.024: D/OpenGLRenderer(2643): Enabling debug mode 0
01-14 10:41:27.204: D/dalvikvm(2643): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 225K, 4% free 7886K/8152K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
01-14 10:41:27.634: D/MediaPlayer(2643): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
01-14 10:41:27.684: W/MediaPlayer(2643): info/warning (701, 0)
01-14 10:42:40.964: E/MediaPlayer(2643): error (1, -2147483648)
01-14 10:42:40.964: E/MediaPlayer(2643): Error (1,-2147483648)
01-14 10:42:40.964: D/VideoView(2643): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

could you please help me for this issues..

Comment: Have you see this tutorial [link](http://www.truiton.com/2013/08/android-videoview-example-with-youtube-playback/). It will help you.

Comment: @i also referred same link only, i already posted my question here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915452/how-to-resolve-media-player-error1-2147483648 but nobody reply to me could you please help me

Comment: @Vivek i am just trying this tutorial http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/03/simple-example-using-videoview-to-play.html, this is simple tutorial only. but i don't know what is the problem.

Comment: is this is valid rtsp url you are using? or Please use some normal url as given in that link.

Comment: but you told me that you refer my link. but your link is different what you have posted.

Comment: if i give normal url like http://www.pocketjourney.com/downloads/pj/video/famous.3gp
my video is working but while i am using that rtsp url as what mentioned in thishttp://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/03/simple-example-using-videoview-to-play.html, it is not working, why?  my requirement is to work rtsp url because i have to play youtube videos in my videoview for that i need to convert from normal youtube url to rtsp url then only my my video will play in videoview

Comment: @Vivek check this link, i used your tutorial only, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915452/how-to-resolve-media-player-error1-2147483648

Comment: did i gave you this link http://www.truiton.com/2013/08/android-videoview-example-with-youtube-playback/  ?

Comment: @Vivek ya, i already used this http://www.truiton.com/2013/08/android-videoview-example-with-youtube-playback/ tutorial, but i am getting same problem, that is what i posted my question there just check it my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915452/how-to-resolve-media-player-error1-2147483648